# What does this C++ statement mean?

Tags: c++

```
void max_idxs(vector<int> &pidxs){
   vector<fragment *> ids;
   max_ids(ids);

   for(size_t i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++){
    int weight_idx = ids[i]->weight_idx; //Get weight index
   }
}
```

In this C++ code, what does it mean by `int weight_idx = ids[i]->weight_idx;`?

What does `->` mean?

Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, the `->` operator is typically used without spaces (e.g. `ids[i]->weight_idx`)

Comment: Weird.  I have never seen `->` used with whitespace around it like that.

Comment: @Shawn D: now there is spaces
@Justin: yes, no spaces in the original code
It was my typing error, I have edited it

Comment: You might benefit from a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to get you started with a solid understanding.

Comment: @GMan: thanks, I will read some books if I got time in the future :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`x->y` means `(*x).y`.  In other words, "take the address pointed to by `x`, and get the variable `y` from the object there".  Here, it means it'll get the `weight_idx` from the `fragment` pointed to by `ids[i]`.

Comment: I'd rather say "take the object...", not "take the address...", but that's not enough to prevent me from up-voting you. `:)`

Comment: sorry, cant know understand the C++ pointer, etc. is it possible not use the "x->y" things? (maintaining the same function)

Comment: @ladyfafa if you want to program C++, you will _have_ to understand pointers.

Comment: @ladyfafa, `x->y` is identical to `(*x).y`.  You can exchange the two anywhere in your code.

Comment: @ladyfafa:  Unfortunately, in order to understand something like this, you're going to have to understand C++ pointers.  There really isn't another equivalent way of doing this.

Comment: Well, if you for any reason _hate_ the `->` notation, you might do `fragment& f = *ids[i]; f.weight_idx`.

Comment: @ladyfafa, Java has references.  If you think of `x` as a reference, then `x->y` is like `x.y` in Java.

Comment: I wouldn't compare Java references to C++ pointers. C++ pointers are much trickier (but I would argue, more powerful and explicit).

Comment: @adam_0, In this case they are conceptually nearly identical, which is why I stated one in terms of the other.

Comment: @ladyfafa:  The problem is not that C++ has pointers, since Java has pointers.  The confusing issue is that, in C++, most objects could be either used directly or through a pointer, while in Java there's primitive types (which aren't referenced through pointers) and class types (which are).  It's arguable that the C++ `->` is the same as the Java `.`, but in that case there's no Java counterpart to C++'s `.`.