# Tricky C code for queue function, what is happening with the pointers?

Tags: c, debugging, code-analysis

I'm trying to understand this C code for modifying queues:

```
  /*
    * create or delete a queue
    * PARAMETERS: QUEUE **qptr - space for, or pointer to, queue
    * int flag -  1 for create, 0 for delete
    * int size - max elements in queue
    */
    void qManage(QUEUE **qptr, int flag, int size){
         if(flag){
                  /* allocate a new queue */
                  *qptr = malloc(sizeof(QUEUE));
                  (*qptr)->head = (*qptr)->count = 0;
                  (*qptr)->que = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
                  (*qptr)->size = size;
                  }
                  else{
                       // delete the current queue
                       (void) free((*qptr)->que);
                       (void) free(*qptr);
                 }
           }
```

What is the `**qptr` parameter? What does  `(*qptr)->head` mean? I know that -> is a pointer to a structure member reference, but I'm lost on what's going on here.   I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: Look for a `typedef` for the `QUEUE` type. It'll be a `struct` that will have a `head` member...

Comment: @sarnold - cool, I see what you mean, yes there's a struct with `int head`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QUEUE** qptr` means that `qptr` is a pointer to a pointer to a `QUEUE` (whatever that is).

`*qptr` is "the memory pointed to by `qptr`", which is thus a pointer to a `QUEUE`.

`x->y` is the same as `(*x).y`. In other words, "take the thing pointed to by `x`, then get its `y`". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3479169/383402 for reference.

So, `(*qptr)->head` is the `head` of the `QUEUE` which is pointed to by the thing *which is pointed to by* `qptr`.

The extra layer of indirection is so that the function can effectively return a `QUEUE*`. In order to return the `QUEUE*`, it takes in a `QUEUE**`, and makes it point to the newly-allocated memory.